# How to fix this regex problem to match optional columns and spaces?

Tags: python, regex

This is my data format with up to 3 columns:

```
WORD, FREQ and TAG
WORD, FREQ
WORD, TAG
WORD
```

The following are some examples:

```
WORD FREQ TAG
dog 100 n
kill 200 v
cat n
united states
united kingdom 100
new york 2 n
```

Where only the first column WORD is required. The second column could be a number or a tag (a-z). I use the re_pattern to parse each line to get each column.

```
words = ['dog 100 n', 'kill 200 v', 'cat n', 'united states', 'united kingdom 100', 'new york 2 n']
re_pattern = re.compile('^(.+?)(\s[0-9]+)?(\s[a-z]+)?$', re.U)

for w in words:
    word, freq, tag = re_pattern.match(w).groups()

    print(word, freq, tag)
```

The output is below:

```
dog  100  n
kill  200  v
cat None  n
united None  states
united kingdom  100 None
new york  2  n
```

As you can see, all others are right, but 'united states' are wrong. It parse 'states' and the tag and None as freq. In this case, there is only one column, WORD, no freq and tag.  How to fix this pattern to get all the patterns right?

Comment: According to your format a single line with two words is interpreted as a word and a tag. Can the definition of a tag be more specific, they seem to be limited to a few select characters?

Comment: 'united states' is a normal word, and 'united' itself is a normal word, if it exists on a line alone.

Comment: What makes "cat n" a word and a tag but "united states" a single word? If the definition of a tag can be made more specific maybe that would help?

Comment: Yes, you are right. What about TAG is a list defined: TAG = ['n', 'nz', 'v', 'vz'] for example.

Comment: Change the part of the regex that picks up tags to only match those strings and you should be good: `(n|nz|v|vz)`

Comment: My my tag count is about 50. It's hard to list in the regex.

Comment: Do the tags follow a pattern? A brute force approach would be to create a large "or" group/match and use it in your regex: `'|'.join(all_tags)`

Comment: How to use an external list in a regex? I can predefine it before applying the regex.

Comment: A regex is just a string, you can use normal string formatting to insert whatever you want into it: `'^(.+?)(\s[0-9]+)?(\s(?:{})+)?$'.format('|'.join(all_tags))`

Comment: @IainShelvington That's a good thing to know and thanks a lot for the technique.

Comment: You should be aware the answer you accepted only works for single letter tags. "cat nz" for example would come out as a single word

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington for pointing that out. I updated my answer to include support for tags that has more than 1 letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that the TAG part is a single letter (see also the comments section), try this pattern:

```
^(.+?)\s*(\b\d+)?\s*(\b[a-z])?$
```

But if the TAG might contain more than 1 letter e.g. `nz`, what we can do to remove the ambiguity between treating `cat aw` as a WORD while `cat nz` as a WORD and a TAG is to list all possible tags in an OR `|` operation:

```
^(.+?)\s*(\b\d+)?\s*(\b(?:n|nz|v|vz))?$
```

**Code:**

```
import re

TAG = ['n', 'nz', 'v', 'vz']

words = ['dog 100 n', 'dog 100 nz', 'kill 200 v', 'cat n', 'cat vz', 'united states', 'united states nz', 'united kingdom 100', 'new york 2 n', 'new york 2 vz']

# Option 1: If using single-letter tags
re_single_letter_tag = re.compile(r'^(.+?)\s*(\b\d+)?\s*(\b[a-z])?$', re.U)
# Option 2: If using a specific set of tags with more than 1 letter
re_multi_tag = re.compile(
    r'^(.+?)\s*(\b\d+)?\s*(\b(?:' + r"|".join(TAG) + r'))?$',
    re.U,
)

for w in words:
    word1, freq1, tag1 = re_single_letter_tag.match(w).groups()  # Option 1
    word2, freq2, tag2 = re_multi_tag .match(w).groups()  # Option 2
    print(w)
    print(f"\t{word1=} {freq1=} {tag1=}")
    print(f"\t{word2=} {freq2=} {tag2=}")
```

**Output**

```
dog 100 n
    word1='dog' freq1='100' tag1='n'
    word2='dog' freq2='100' tag2='n'
dog 100 nz
    word1='dog 100 nz' freq1=None tag1=None
    word2='dog' freq2='100' tag2='nz'
kill 200 v
    word1='kill' freq1='200' tag1='v'
    word2='kill' freq2='200' tag2='v'
cat n
    word1='cat' freq1=None tag1='n'
    word2='cat' freq2=None tag2='n'
cat vz
    word1='cat vz' freq1=None tag1=None
    word2='cat' freq2=None tag2='vz'
united states
    word1='united states' freq1=None tag1=None
    word2='united states' freq2=None tag2=None
united states nz
    word1='united states nz' freq1=None tag1=None
    word2='united states' freq2=None tag2='nz'
united kingdom 100
    word1='united kingdom' freq1='100' tag1=None
    word2='united kingdom' freq2='100' tag2=None
new york 2 n
    word1='new york' freq1='2' tag1='n'
    word2='new york' freq2='2' tag2='n'
new york 2 vz
    word1='new york 2 vz' freq1=None tag1=None
    word2='new york' freq2='2' tag2='vz'
```

Where:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(.+?)` - Non-greedy matching of the "WORD" part. This will capture the least possible characters that would still satisfy the next parts capturing their own parts. Treat this as if the next parts would be prioritized to capture their parts first before this pattern will get its share.
- `\s*` - Any number of spaces
- `(\b\d+)?` - Optionally match the "FREQ" part
- `\s*` - Any number of spaces
- `(\b[a-z])?` - Optionally match the "TAG" part. It is mandatory to put the boundary `\b` so that this wouldn't get the last letter supposedly for the "WORD" e.g. "s" in "united states".
- `(\b(?:n|nz|v|vz))?`- Optionally match the "TAG" part from a specific list of possible tags
- `$` - End of string

Comment: It seem working! It's a good learning the use of \b and \d

Comment: Glad it helped. Note that as being discussed in the other comment section, the format of the tag must be consistent. In my answer, it assumes that the tag is a single lowercase letter separated by a space/word-boundary. If you have tags with 2-letters such as "nm", then we have to identify all of them so that we will treat "cat aw" as a WORD and "cat nm" as a WORD and TAG (see the ambiguity?). In that case, I'm afraid the only way of doing it is listing all possible tags in an or `|` operation in the regex.

Comment: I understand that now and thanks.

Comment: @marlon I updated my answer to include another option when the tags contain multi-letters. I believe it might help you better with your use case :)